# store a bunch of configuration information in scala

Tags: scala, data-structures

I'm using the following code to read configuration information from a configuration file,

```
val prop = new Properties()
prop.load(new FileInputStream("logininfo.cfg")) 
val host = getProperty("host", prop)
val user = getProperty("user", prop)
...
```

I'm wondering if there is a good way to store all this information, like host, user, etc. in Scala.
Currently, I'm using a class like:

```
 class Init_Info {
    var user: String = ""
    var host: String = ""
    ...
  }
```

I'm wondering if there is another way to do this job.

Comment: check out https://github.com/kevinmeredith/typesafe_config_read_env_var

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) is a good library for what you seek. It allows you to store your config in HOCON (a JSON superset).

If you choose this solution, you can also check out [Ficus](https://github.com/ceedubs/ficus), which provides a nice Scala wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You approach is valid, though mutability may be avoided here for instance by defining a `Map` as follows,

```
val prop = new Properties()
prop.load(new FileInputStream("logininfo.cfg")) 

val initInfo = List("host","user")).map(p => p -> getProperty(p,prop)).toMap
```

Then fetch values for instance with

```
initInfo.getOrElse("host",sys.error("not found"))
```